# Как сделать аналог "бегущей строки" с помощью swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper

Проблема в том, что даже при `delay: 0` происходит остановка перед сменой слайда. Как ее убрать полностью?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('#js-carousel', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  speed: 2000,
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 0,
  },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swiper-container" id="js-carousel">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 1" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 2" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 3" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 4" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 5" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 6" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 7" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 8" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 9" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 10" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что конкретно нужно? чтобы слайдер постоянно был в движении как бегущая строка?

Comment: @Vearo, Да, как бегущая строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в стилях заменить `transition-timing-function` на `linear`:

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
          transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}
```

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('#js-carousel', {  
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  speed: 2000,
  loop: true,
  //allowTouchMove: false, // можно ещё отключить свайп
  autoplay: {
    delay: 0,
    disableOnInteraction: false // или сделать так, чтобы восстанавливался autoplay после взаимодействия
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
          transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}

.swiper-slide img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swiper-container" id="js-carousel">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 1" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 2" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 3" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 4" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 5" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 6" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 7" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 8" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 9" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="text-align: center">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=Img 10" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Очень здорово, что Вы написали ответ. Помимо кода, старайтесь также давать хотя бы минимальные комментарии, которые бы объясняли, что Вы сделали, в чем, возможно, была ошибка ТС и т.д. Ответы просматривают много новичков в программировании и для них может быть мало просто работающего кода. Чем понятнее и подробнее будет расписан ответ, тем он будет полезнее, тем больше будет Ваш личный вклад в сообщество и тем выше у Вас будет рейтинг.